# What is difference between Taylor series and Legendre polynomial?

Tags: image-processing

As i know, taylor series is used for analysis f(x).
So if i have many orders, i can approximate f(x).

In this point of view, what is difference Legendre Polynomials?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not DSP - try http:math.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: //paul i don't think so because this is not just math. I'm asking you in point of view of DSP. 

   

// then what is your DSP ? I am very curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taylor series approximation of a function involves matching derivatives of the function and the polynomial *at one point*. All information to construct the Taylor series is obtained from the function and its derivatives at that point. So you get a smooth approximation around that chosen point. In the case of approximation by Legendre polynomials, you approximate a function *in an interval* in a least squares sense. The function values in this interval as well as its derivatives will generally be different from the corresponding values of the approximating polynomial, but the mean squared error in the chosen interval attains a minimum for a given degree of the polynomial.